# Loop not looping through files in DIR (Outer Loop)

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code that works, a DIR loop that loops through CSV files, does code, then calls next until the end. The problem started when I added another loop within this loop, DIR loop to call PDF's...

I have stepped through the code and the problem is the first outer loop not calling the next CSV (the PDF loop works fine). I've done some research but can't make any adjustments work.

Any assistance is appreciated. I don't mind not being given the answer if you could show me where to look to resolve.

```
Sub Coles_claims_consolidation()
'Coles Claims Import Macro

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object



    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\csv_macro\")
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Debug.Print oFile.Name
    Next 'oFile

        'Loop through each file in the folder
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        If oFile.Name Like "*.pdf" Then
            FileCopy oFile, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FiName2 & ".pdf"
        End If
    Next oFile

    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing



End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think [`DIR` function could be called recursively.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function). Using [File System Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/aa711216(v=vs.90)) would be better option.

Comment: I could add another DIR loop as long as its not inside a previous loop? In the code above, I could move the pdf DIR loop to after where i save ColesAllWB (at end of code)

Comment: it may solve problem. Give it a try

Comment: I have trimmed the code to the above. I researched scripting and the code works. DIR loop works, however the only part that doesn't work now is the filecopy. the debug prints. no errors are given

Comment: What does filecopy doesn't work mean? What is/isn't happening?

Comment: Nothing is happening.. Not copying pdf from macro folder to workbook.path folder. the debug 'finds' the pdf

Comment: Can I ask a quick question: Can you nest 2 or more FSO within a loop? As you cant nest 2 DIR within a loop.

Comment: @alowflyingpig Users are only pinged if you add the `@` and their name - otherwise they may never see your comment - an exception would be that the post owner (you) will always see a comment. What are you trying to do, exactly? (If it's complex you may have to start a new question so you can add all your details - comments are somewhat difficult to do this in.)

Comment: @K.Davis it was just a general question. whether or not I should start adapting to scripting over using DIR Loop.. For future reference..

Comment: I think it's easier to use FSO - it has many more methods than `Dir` does and for the most part, if you can use `Dir` you can also use `FSO`, but it's not always the same in reverse. I believe I once read somewhere that FSO in general has better performance over Dir, but I have never personally tested it and cannot confirm that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`oFile` already has the file path included with it. You should set the target file path in `oFolder` and loop within that directory.

**If you only want `.pdf` files** then keep the `If oFile.Name` line - otherwise if you want all files then delete the if statement.

```
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\csv_macro\")

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    If oFile.Name Like "*.pdf" Then
        FileCopy oFile, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FiName2 & ".pdf"
    End If
Next oFile
```

Answer (score 0):

## A Working Solution?

Change the line

```
oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile) = FiName2
```

to

```
FiName2 = oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile)
```

EDIT:

Is this your final solution then?

```
Sub Coles_claims_consolidation()
'Coles Claims Import Macro

    Dim sPath As String
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim FiName2 As String

    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\csv_macro\"

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        FiName2 = oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile)
        If oFile.Name Like "*.pdf" Then
            FileCopy oFile, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FiName2 & ".pdf"
        End If
    Next oFile

    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing

End Sub
```